# Use D3 force simulation as pure function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, functional-programming, d3-force-directed

Im using d3-force to do collision detection:

```
function layout(nodesWithXY) {
  const simulation = forceSimulation(nodesWithXY)
    .force('collide', forceCollide(4.5))
    .stop()
    .tick(300)

  return simulation.nodes()
}
```

I don't want the graph to be animated so I just get the final state of the nodes after 300 ticks.

But it would be nice if I could run the simulation again (with the same `nodesWithXY`) and get the same result. This would make it easier to use in react.

Is this possible?
e.g. by running more iterations or tweaking alpa and decay values?

Answer (score 2):

So a few weeks ago I stumbled over this post from Mike Bostock in 2016: "Using phyllotaxis, d3-force initialization is now deterministic! Consistent across reload and across browsers." https://twitter.com/mbostock/status/725124754701717504?lang=de

If I set the inital values for x and y to `NaN` I get deterministic results. This is somewhat described here: https://github.com/d3/d3-force#simulation_nodes

```js
const nodes = d3.range(5).map(() => ({
    // use NaN to make deterministic
    x: NaN,
    y: NaN
}));
const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(10))
    .stop()
    .tick(300)
console.log(nodes.map(d => d.x))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

So it is possible as long as I don't need initial positions

Answer (score 0):

In short: a D3 force simulation cannot and **should not** be a pure function (that is, a function that *always returns the same values if the same arguments are passed in*).

The reason is that a simulation, like a physical system, evolves chaotically, being [highly dependent on how the first interactions happened](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory#Sensitivity_to_initial_conditions). By it's very design, a D3 force simulation is [nondeterministic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_algorithm).

We can easily demonstrate this in a basic simulation:

```js
const nodes = d3.range(5).map(() => ({
  x: 100,
  y: 100
}));
const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(10))
  .stop()
  .tick(300)
console.log(nodes.map(d => d.x))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

If we run that snippet several times, we'll get different results. For instance, the `x` position of the nodes:

> 1st time: [120.1198, 110.0542, 100.2805, 89.5732, 79.972]
>
> 2nd time: [67.6898, 83.854, 99.5493, 116.7441, 132.1625]
>
> 3rd time: [133.1773, 116.5792, 100.4626, 82.8064, 66.9742]
>
> etc...

You can see this by yourself, just click the <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> button several times.

That being said, if you're expecting a D3 force simulation to behave like a pure function, you're using the wrong tool for the task.

Comment: You can wrap it in a monad/functor though, which defers the effectful computation while composing/combining it with other functions/actions, until you actually run it.

Comment: What I did in the end is basically a memoized function. I store the simulation result and the parameters and if the parameters did not change I return the stored result.

Comment: But any suggestions for how to do deterministic collision detection / positioning in js? (with or without d3)

Comment: @errnesto no, I don't know any library that does that.

Comment: https://ialab.it.monash.edu/webcola/ looks interesting. I did not try it out though